# cocoapods: cant install latest AMScrollingNavbar through cocoapods

Tags: terminal, cocoapods

pod --version : 0.38.2

Unable to install latest version of AMScrollingNavbar through cocoapods, if I don't specify the version, it installs version 1.5.1.

If I specify version as: pod 'AMScrollingNavbar', '~> 2.0.0'
I get: Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
 `AMScrollingNavbar (~> 2.0.0)` required by `Podfile`

If I do: pod 'AMScrollingNavbar (~> 2.0.0)' 
I get: Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `AMScrollingNavbar (~> 2.0.0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed to pod 'AMScrollingNavbar', '~> 2.0.0-beta7' and installed latest one.